# How to create an entity reference field in Drupal 8 programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to create an entity reference field in Drupal 8 using my custom module. Like when someone clicks a link on a Drupal page, an entity reference field would be created in the page node type automatically.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

So I can hopefully find this faster if I need to again...

Create field storage:

```
 if (!$field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field_name)) {
   FieldStorageConfig::create([
     'field_name' => $field_name,
     'entity_type' => $entity_type,
     'type' => $type,
     'cardinality' => -1,

     // Optional to target entity types.
     'settings' => [
       'target_type' => $entity_target_type, // Ex: node, taxonomy_term.
     ],
   ])->save();
 }
```

Create field:

```
FieldConfig::create([
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'entity_type' => $entity_type,
  'bundle' => $bundle,
  'label' => $label,
  'cardinality' => -1,

  // Optional to target bundles.
  'settings' => [
    'handler' => 'default',
    'handler_settings' => [
      'target_bundles' => [
        $vid1,
        $vid2,
      ],
    ],
  ],
])->save();
```

Comment: did you find any official documentation on your code above? Showing the key values?

It should be noted that the "settings" will map (to a certain extent) the form field names found on the settings page. So in order to have a checkbox checked for a given content type; `'page' => 'page'`.

Comment: I was unable to find much documentation online, which is a major reason I posted here. However the core Field module has a good example of this in the `EntityReferenceAutoCreateTest` class. The example there uses the `target_bundles` and `target_type` as well. Also, if you look at the settings page the checkboxes do too.

Answer (score 3):

This will create an entity reference field for `node` content types with the `article` bundle.

```
$form['node_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title' => $this->t('Node'),
    '#target_type' => 'node',
    '#selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['article']],
    '#tags' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
  );
```

Note you can change `target_type` for other entities like `taxonomy_term`.

Comment: This code snippet supposed to be used in the context of rendering a form. Therefore it adds the extra field widget to the form, but does nothing about _creating the field itself_ – as OP asked. Afterall, once this form is being submitted, the data inserted into this widget will be lost, because the storage is not prepared for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = "YOUR TITLE";
$node->type = "YOUR_NODE_TYPE";
 ....
$node->field_customer_nid[$node->language][]['target_id'] =    $form_state['values']['entity id'];


 ...
 node_submit($node);
 node_save($node);
```

Comment: You might want to add some accompanying text to this. Its not overly clear what you're demonstrating.

Answer (score -2):

You can get help from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Plugin!DataType!EntityReference.php/8

Or you can download sample entity examples too https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Or you can use my method too which is as below:

**Set up module
content_entity_example.info.yml**

```
name: Content Entity Example
type: module
description: 'Provides ContentEntityExampleContact entity.'
package: Example modules
core: 8.x
# These modules are required by the tests, must be available at bootstrap time
dependencies:
  - options
  - entity_reference
  - examples
```

Creating a content entity type in Drupal 8

We will create a 'Contact' entity to add, edit and delete People (Contacts). It is fully fieldable and uses most of the new entity concepts available in Drupal 8.

**Routing
content_entity_example.routing.yml**

```
# This file brings everything together. Very nifty!

# Route name can be used in sevaral place (links, redirects, local actions etc.)
entity.content_entity_example_contact.canonical:
  path: '/content_entity_example_contact/{content_entity_example_contact}'
  defaults:
  # Calls the view controller, defined in the annotation of the contact entity
    _entity_view: 'content_entity_example_contact'
    _title: 'Contact Content'
  requirements:
  # Calls the access controller of the entity, $operation 'view'
    _entity_access: 'content_entity_example_contact.view'

entity.content_entity_example_contact.collection:
  path: '/content_entity_example_contact/list'
  defaults:
  # Calls the list controller, defined in the annotation of the contact entity.
    _entity_list: 'content_entity_example_contact'
    _title: 'Contact List'
  requirements:
  # Checks for permission directly.
    _permission: 'view contact entity'

content_entity_example.contact_add:
  path: '/content_entity_example_contact/add'
  defaults:
  # Calls the form.add controller, defined in the contact entity.
    _entity_form: content_entity_example_contact.add
    _title: 'Add Contact'
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'content_entity_example_contact'

entity.content_entity_example_contact.edit_form:
  path: '/content_entity_example_contact/{content_entity_example_contact}/edit'
  defaults:
  # Calls the form.edit controller, defined in the contact entity.
    _entity_form: content_entity_example_contact.edit
    _title: 'Edit Contact'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'content_entity_example_contact.edit'

entity.content_entity_example_contact.delete_form:
  path: '/contact/{content_entity_example_contact}/delete'
  defaults:
    # Calls the form.delete controller, defined in the contact entity.
    _entity_form: content_entity_example_contact.delete
    _title: 'Delete Contact'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'content_entity_example_contact.delete'

content_entity_example.contact_settings:
  path: 'admin/structure/content_entity_example_contact_settings'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\content_entity_example\Form\ContactSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Contact Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer contact entity'
```

The route names for actions defined in the 'link' section of the entity annotation must follow the right pattern. For details please see the Content Entity Class below.

**content_entity_example.links.menu.yml**

In combination with the routing file, this replaces hook_menu for the module.

```
# Define the menu links for this module

entity.content_entity_example_contact.collection:
  title: 'Content Entity Example: Contacts Listing'
  route_name: entity.content_entity_example_contact.collection
  description: 'List Contacts'
  weight: 10
content_entity_example_contact.admin.structure.settings:
  title: Contact Settings
  description: 'Configure Contact entity'
  route_name:  content_entity_example.contact_settings
  parent: system.admin_structure
```

**content_entity_example.links.action.yml**

```
# All action links for this module

content_entity_example.contact_add:
  # Which route will be called by the link
  route_name: content_entity_example.contact_add
  title: 'Add Contact'

  # Where will the link appear, defined by route name.
  appears_on:
    - entity.content_entity_example_contact.collection
    - entity.content_entity_example_contact.canonical
```

Comment: This seems to be code for creating a custom entity type? But, the question is about creating an entity reference field.